# AS3 library for handling Apple HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http-live-streaming

I wonder what is the best solution for handling HLS in action script.
[This very](http://code.google.com/p/apple-http-osmf/) project seems to be quite mature, but somewhat outdated. 
GitHub shows nothing relevant.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the project you link to?

Comment: @vipw, I've read some user reports and it looks like that recently it is not very well tested and there are cases when it doesn't handle correctly playlist. Regarding the fact that playback problems sometimes are very hard to detect/debug I'm quite careful. Beside, there is a list of issues, and some of this issues also look not so harmless - http://code.google.com/p/apple-http-osmf/issues/list.

Comment: I kind of doubt you'll find anything more mature. Probably the project just needs a new maintainer, thankfully the license is permissive.

Answer (score 1):

JW Player supports playing HLS from Flash.
http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/hls-rtmp-live-streaming/